# Random number generator in Python Canvas

Tags: python, canvas

Hi I need help with this project to school. Everything is woriking but part where I ask in terminal what was number it always print it was't that number.

```
import tkinter
import random


canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

number = canvas.create_text(400, 200, text=random.randint(10000, 100000))

def prec():
    canvas.create_rectangle(400 - 50, 200 - 50, 400 + 50, 200 + 50, outline="white", fill="white")
canvas.after(2000, prec)

guess = input("What number was there?: ")
guess = int(guess)


if guess == number:
    canvas.create_text(400, 100, text="Correct", font="arial 20")
else:
    canvas.create_text(400, 100, text="Incorrect", font="arial 20")


canvas.mainloop()
```

Everytime I try it says "Incorrect" but it' correct. I don't know what to do to make it work so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you think `canvas.create_text()` returns? (Hint: it isn't a number). [Look it up](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html)

Answer (score 0):

the variable `number` is an object ID of a text object.

```py
number = canvas.create_text(400, 200, text=random.randint(10000, 100000))
```

so you're not comparing the guess with the number displayed, but rather with that object ID. (which also happens to be an int [per the tkinter docs] but that's beside the point)

what you want is maybe to generate the number first, then use it in the canvas and in your value comparison.

```py
import tkinter
import random


canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

# generate number
random_number = random.randint(10000, 100000)

# place number in canvas
number = canvas.create_text(400, 200, text=random_number)

def prec():
    canvas.create_rectangle(400 - 50, 200 - 50, 400 + 50, 200 + 50, outline="white", fill="white")
canvas.after(2000, prec)

guess = input("What number was there?: ")
guess = int(guess)


# compare guess to number
if guess == random_number :
    canvas.create_text(400, 100, text="Correct", font="arial 20")
else:
    canvas.create_text(400, 100, text="Incorrect", font="arial 20")

canvas.mainloop()
```

if the future, consider using a debugger to see the values of all variables